# How to structure MongoDB for multi-field query?

Tags: database-design, mongodb

Right now, we have a `Post` collection that the users query based on their `locale`. The collection looks like this:

```
Post {
   userId: String
   text: String
   locale: String
   ...
   ...
}
```

And a `User` collection that looks like this:

```
User {
   id: String
   username: String
   locale: String
   ...
   ...
}
```

Now that the business model changes, we need to make some changes to how the users fetch posts. So, instead of querying only on `locale`, they will also need to fetch posts based on some other data:

1. users they frequently chat with
2. users with 3 or more common interests (this feature is not implemented yet)
3. users they manually choose to see

Considering data 1 and 3, I came up with the `UserData` collection, which looks like this:

```
UserData {
   userId: String
   chatUserIds: Array<String>
   favoriteUserIds: Array<String>
}
```

The idea behind this collection is that every time the app launches, this collection will be fetched in order to gather the data for the current user, and after that, the `Post` query will be made like this:

> query `Post`, where `locale` equals `currentUserLocale` and `userId` is contained in `joined(chatUserIds, favoriteUserIds)`, sorted by `createdAt` descendingly.

As for data no 2, "users with 3 or more common interests", I’ve decided to add to the `UserData` collection an array of strings, containing the names of the interests the user chose during signup, so it’ll be updated to this:

```
UserData {
   userId: String
   chatUserIds: Array<String>
   favoriteUserIds: Array<String>
   interests: Array<String> // ["Sports", "TV", ...]
}
```

Now, this is the part that I'm struggling with; how can I efficiently query the `Post` collection, to get posts where the poster has 3 or more common interests with the current user?

I thought updating the `Post` collection to make it have its posters' `interests`, but I don’t know how to make a query to get posts where the current user has at least 3 matches with each post's `interests`.

Essentially, this is what I need:

> query `Post`, where `locale` equals `currentUserLocale`, `userId` is contained in `joined(chatUserIds, favoriteUserIds)` and `interests` contains at least 3 of `currentUserInterests`, sorted by `createdAt` descendingly.

Any idea will be appreciated greatly!!!